# using this keyword in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a javascript class with this keyword like below

```
if (this[this.props.steps[i].stepId].sendState !== undefined) {
            this.setState({
              allStates: {
                ...this.state.allStates,
                [this.props.steps[i].stepId]: this[
                  this.props.steps[i].stepId
                ].sendState()
              }
            });
          }
```

I converted above file to ts
but this line gives typescript error -> `this[this.props.steps[i].stepId].sendState`

This is the error given by typescript

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Wizard'.ts(7053)
```

how to write above line in typescript ?

[image]

This is the whole typescript code with errors

```
 class Wizard extends React.Component<any,any> {
  static defaultProps :any;
  static propTypes :any
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    var width;
    if (this.props.steps.length === 1) {
      width = "100%";
    } else {
      if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
        if (this.props.steps.length !== 3) {
          width = "50%";
        } else {
          width = 100 / 3 + "%";
        }
      } else {
        if (this.props.steps.length === 2) {
          width = "50%";
        } else {
          width = 100 / 3 + "%";
        }
      }
    }
    this.state = {
      currentStep: 0,
      color: this.props.color,
      nextButton: this.props.steps.length > 1 ? true : false,
      previousButton: false,
      finishButton: this.props.steps.length === 1 ? true : false,
      width: width,
      movingTabStyle: {
        transition: "transform 0s"
      },
      allStates: {}
    };
    this.navigationStepChange = this.navigationStepChange.bind(this);
    this.refreshAnimation = this.refreshAnimation.bind(this);
    this.previousButtonClick = this.previousButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.previousButtonClick = this.previousButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.finishButtonClick = this.finishButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.updateWidth = this.updateWidth.bind(this);
  }
  wizard:any = React.createRef();
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refreshAnimation(0);
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }
  updateWidth() {
    this.refreshAnimation(this.state.currentStep);
  }
  navigationStepChange(key:any) {
    if (this.props.steps) {
      var validationState = true;
      if (key > this.state.currentStep) {
        for (var i = this.state.currentStep; i < key; i++) {
          if (this[this.props.steps[i].stepId].sendState !== undefined) {
            this.setState({
              allStates: {
                ...this.state.allStates,
                [this.props.steps[i].stepId]: this[
                  this.props.steps[i].stepId
                ].sendState()
              }
            });
          }
          if (
            this[this.props.steps[i].stepId].isValidated !== undefined &&
            this[this.props.steps[i].stepId].isValidated() === false
          ) {
            validationState = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (validationState) {
        this.setState({
          currentStep: key,
          nextButton: this.props.steps.length > key + 1 ? true : false,
          previousButton: key > 0 ? true : false,
          finishButton: this.props.steps.length === key + 1 ? true : false
        });
        this.refreshAnimation(key);
      }
    }
  }
  nextButtonClick() {
    if (
      (this.props.validate &&
        ((this[this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId].isValidated !==
          undefined &&
          this[
            this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId
          ].isValidated()) ||
          this[this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId].isValidated ===
            undefined)) ||
      this.props.validate === undefined
    ) {
      if (
        this[this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId].sendState !==
        undefined
      ) {
        this.setState({
          allStates: {
            ...this.state.allStates,
            [this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId]: this[
              this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId
            ].sendState()
          }
        });
      }
      var key = this.state.currentStep + 1;
      this.setState({
        currentStep: key,
        nextButton: this.props.steps.length > key + 1 ? true : false,
        previousButton: key > 0 ? true : false,
        finishButton: this.props.steps.length === key + 1 ? true : false
      });
      this.refreshAnimation(key);
    }
  }
  previousButtonClick() {
    if (
      this[this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId].sendState !==
      undefined
    ) {
      this.setState({
        allStates: {
          ...this.state.allStates,
          [this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId]: this[
            this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId
          ].sendState()
        }
      });
    }
    var key = this.state.currentStep - 1;
    if (key >= 0) {
      this.setState({
        currentStep: key,
        nextButton: this.props.steps.length > key + 1 ? true : false,
        previousButton: key > 0 ? true : false,
        finishButton: this.props.steps.length === key + 1 ? true : false
      });
      this.refreshAnimation(key);
    }
  }
  finishButtonClick() {
    if (
      (this.props.validate === false &&
        this.props.finishButtonClick !== undefined) ||
      (this.props.validate &&
        ((this[this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId].isValidated !==
          undefined &&
          this[
            this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId
          ].isValidated()) ||
          this[this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId].isValidated ===
            undefined) &&
        this.props.finishButtonClick !== undefined)
    ) {
      this.setState(
        {
          allStates: {
            ...this.state.allStates,
            [this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId]: this[
              this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId
            ].sendState()
          }
        },
        () => {
          this.props.finishButtonClick(this.state.allStates);
        }
      );
    }
  }
  refreshAnimation(index:any) {
    var total = this.props.steps.length;
    var li_width = 100 / total;
    var total_steps = this.props.steps.length;
    var move_distance =
      this.wizard.current.children[0].offsetWidth / total_steps;
    var index_temp = index;
    var vertical_level = 0;

    var mobile_device = window.innerWidth < 600 && total > 3;

    if (mobile_device) {
      move_distance = this.wizard.current.children[0].offsetWidth / 2;
      index_temp = index % 2;
      li_width = 50;
    }

    this.setState({ width: li_width + "%" });

    var step_width = move_distance;
    move_distance = move_distance * index_temp;

    var current = index + 1;

    if (current === 1 || (mobile_device === true && index % 2 === 0)) {
      move_distance -= 8;
    } else if (
      current === total_steps ||
      (mobile_device === true && index % 2 === 1)
    ) {
      move_distance += 8;
    }

    if (mobile_device) {
      vertical_level = parseInt((index / 2).toString(), 10);
      vertical_level = vertical_level * 38;
    }
    var movingTabStyle = {
      width: step_width,
      transform:
        "translate3d(" + move_distance + "px, " + vertical_level + "px, 0)",
      transition: "all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.29, 1.42, 0.79, 1)"
    };
    this.setState({ movingTabStyle: movingTabStyle });
  }
  render() {
    const { classes, title, subtitle, color, steps } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.wizardContainer} ref={this.wizard}>
        <Card className={classes.card}>
          <div className={classes.wizardHeader}>
            <h3 className={classes.title}>{title}</h3>
            <h5 className={classes.subtitle}>{subtitle}</h5>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.wizardNavigation}>
            <ul className={classes.nav}>
              {steps.map((prop:any, key:any) => {
                return (
                  <li
                    className={classes.steps}
                    key={key}
                    style={{ width: this.state.width }}
                  >
                    <a
                      href="#pablo"
                      className={classes.stepsAnchor}
                      onClick={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        this.navigationStepChange(key);
                      }}
                    >
                      {prop.stepName}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
            <div
              className={classes.movingTab + " " + classes[color]}
              style={this.state.movingTabStyle}
            >
              {steps[this.state.currentStep].stepName}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.content}>
            {steps.map((prop:any, key:any) => {
              const stepContentClasses = cx({
                [classes.stepContentActive]: this.state.currentStep === key,
                [classes.stepContent]: this.state.currentStep !== key
              });
              return (
                <div className={stepContentClasses} key={key}>
                  <prop.stepComponent
                    innerRef={(node:any) => (this[prop.stepId] = node)}
                    allStates={this.state.allStates}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div className={classes.footer}>
            <div className={classes.left}>
              {this.state.previousButton ? (
                <Button
                  className={this.props.previousButtonClasses}
                  onClick={() => this.previousButtonClick()}
                >
                  {this.props.previousButtonText}
                </Button>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            <div className={classes.right}>
              {this.state.nextButton ? (
                <Button
                  color="rose"
                  className={this.props.nextButtonClasses}
                  onClick={() => this.nextButtonClick()}
                >
                  {this.props.nextButtonText}
                </Button>
              ) : null}
              {this.state.finishButton ? (
                <Button
                  color="rose"
                  className={this.props.finishButtonClasses}
                  onClick={() => this.finishButtonClick()}
                >
                  {this.props.finishButtonText}
                </Button>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            <div className={classes.clearfix} />
          </div>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Wizard.defaultProps = {
  color: "rose",
  title: "Here should go your title",
  subtitle: "And this would be your subtitle",
  previousButtonText: "Previous",
  previousButtonClasses: "",
  nextButtonClasses: "",
  nextButtonText: "Next",
  finishButtonClasses: "",
  finishButtonText: "Finish"
};

Wizard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  steps: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      stepName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      stepComponent: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      stepId: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  ).isRequired,
  color: PropTypes.oneOf([
    "primary",
    "warning",
    "danger",
    "success",
    "info",
    "rose"
  ]),
  title: PropTypes.string,
  subtitle: PropTypes.string,
  previousButtonClasses: PropTypes.string,
  previousButtonText: PropTypes.string,
  nextButtonClasses: PropTypes.string,
  nextButtonText: PropTypes.string,
  finishButtonClasses: PropTypes.string,
  finishButtonText: PropTypes.string,
  finishButtonClick: PropTypes.func,
  validate: PropTypes.bool
};

export default withStyles(wizardStyle)(Wizard);
```

Comment: Technically, what you've written could be valid code, but using `[]` on `this` to access fields by index/key would be surprising. Can you post some more of your code (not screenshots, text code) so that we can try to see what should be going on here?

Comment: Try using this, `this[parseInt(this.props.steps[i].stepId)].sendState`

Comment: @jnpdx I updated the description.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan your suggestion didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The part of your code which is giving you trouble is where you are trying to store `ref` objects for each of your steps.  You are trying to store these as top-level properties on your `Wizard` instance, but you haven't declared them anywhere so typescript doesn't know that they exist.  You will get errors when you try to set them or access them.

I would caution against storing them as top level properties as this is both harder to type properly and prone to errors.  What happens if you have a step whose `stepId` is the same as the name of one of your methods?

I *mostly* understand what's going on in your code.  I'm assuming that the `innerRef` prop on the component is a function that receives the `HTMLElement` as its argument.  It doesn't seem to be a `RefObject` like `this.wizard` since you are not accessing the `.current` property.  In my opinion you would be better off ditching the refs and storing the state in this component.  But I want to actually address your question rather than side-stepping it, so I'll do my best to annotate what you have here with only a few changes.

I am storing a keyed object of refs to a property `stepRefs`.  In typescript, class properties need to be declared, so I include this outside of the constructor:

```
// dictionary of StepRefs keyed by stepId
stepRefs: Record<string, StepElement> = {};
```

One of the things that I am changing is adding helper functions so you don't need to have things like `this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId` in multiple places.

```
// helper returns a stepId from props by index
getStepId(i: number): string {
  return this.props.steps[i].stepId;
}
// helper returns the stepId for the current step
getCurrentStepId(): string {
  return this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId;
}
// helper returns the element ref for a stepId
// this assumes that an element has already been set.  you could include undefined in the return to be safe
getStepRef(stepId: string): StepElement {
  return this.stepRefs[stepId];
}
```

There's a lot of redundancy in your `if` conditions that can be cleaned up through re-ordering. By switching to typescript, you might be able to get rid of some of your `!== undefined` checks by requiring that certain properties must always be defined.

I think there are some packages that can convert your existing `propTypes` declaration to typescript but I just looked at things by hand because in some places, like `stepComponent`, you need to be a lot more specific than what was in your `propTypes`.

```
// this defines the properties that we want to access on the step ref
interface StepElement {
  isValidated?: () => boolean;
  sendState?: () => any; // what is this really?  a boolean?
}

// you use this in a few places so I gave it a type alias
type AllStates = Record<string, any>; // this `any` here corresponds to the return type of sendState()

// this defines the props that we provide to the step component
interface StepComponentProps {
  innerRef: (node: StepElement) => void;
  allStates: AllStates;
}

// the complete step object for the props array
interface Step {
  stepName: string;
  stepComponent: React.ComponentType<StepComponentProps>;
  stepId: string;
}
```

I was able to fix all of the errors related to `this[key]` access.  There is one remaining error that has to do with knowing that `this.props.color` will always be defined due to the `defaultProps`.  I don't usually work with class components and `defaultProps` so I'm not sure of the best way to address this.  In your destructuring line, you can do `(this.props as Required<WizardProps>)` and that will work but I bet there is something better.

I had to do some extra typing in order to access `.offsetWidth` on the children of the wizard ref.  The `children` of an `HTMLDivElement` is typed as `HTMLCollection` where `children[0]` is `Element`.  Not all `Element`s have an `offsetWidth` property.  But in your component there is only one possible type of child -- whatever `Card` is.  So I've basically just said that our ref is to a `div` whose children have an `offsetWidth` property.  I added an early `return` to `refreshAnimation` in case `this.wizard.current` is `null`.

```
wizard: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement & {children: {offsetWidth: number}[]}> = React.createRef();
```

Complete Code:

```
type Color = "primary" | "warning" | "danger" | "success" | "info" | "rose";

interface StepElement {
  isValidated?: () => boolean;
  sendState?: () => any; // what is this really?  a boolean?
}

type AllStates = Record<string, any>; // this any here corresponds to the return type of sendState()

interface StepComponentProps {
  innerRef: (node: StepElement) => void;
  allStates: AllStates;
}

interface Step {
  stepName: string;
  stepComponent: React.ComponentType<StepComponentProps>;
  stepId: string;
}

interface RequiredProps {
  classes: Record<string, string>
  steps: Step[];
};

interface OptionalProps {
  color: Color;
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
  previousButtonClasses: string;
  previousButtonText: string;
  nextButtonClasses: string;
  nextButtonText: string;
  finishButtonClasses: string;
  finishButtonText: string;
  finishButtonClick: (allStates: AllStates) => void;
  validate: boolean;
}

type WizardProps = RequiredProps & Partial<OptionalProps>

interface WizardState {
  currentStep: number;
  color: Color;
  nextButton: boolean;
  previousButton: boolean;
  finishButton: boolean;
  width: string;
  movingTabStyle: React.CSSProperties;
  allStates: AllStates;
}

class Wizard extends React.Component<WizardProps, WizardState> {
  static defaultProps: OptionalProps;
  static propTypes: any;
  constructor(props: Required<WizardProps>) { // all props required because defaults are included
    super(props);
    var width;
    if (this.props.steps.length === 1) {
      width = "100%";
    } else {
      if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
        if (this.props.steps.length !== 3) {
          width = "50%";
        } else {
          width = 100 / 3 + "%";
        }
      } else {
        if (this.props.steps.length === 2) {
          width = "50%";
        } else {
          width = 100 / 3 + "%";
        }
      }
    }
    this.state = {
      currentStep: 0,
      color: props.color, // I actually get a TS error on this.props since it's only required when defaults are included
      nextButton: this.props.steps.length > 1 ? true : false,
      previousButton: false,
      finishButton: this.props.steps.length === 1 ? true : false,
      width: width,
      movingTabStyle: {
        transition: "transform 0s"
      },
      allStates: {}
    };
    this.navigationStepChange = this.navigationStepChange.bind(this);
    this.refreshAnimation = this.refreshAnimation.bind(this);
    this.previousButtonClick = this.previousButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.previousButtonClick = this.previousButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.finishButtonClick = this.finishButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.updateWidth = this.updateWidth.bind(this);
  }
  // ref to a div element
  wizard: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = React.createRef();
  // dictionary of StepRefs keyed by stepId
  stepRefs: Record<string, StepElement> = {};
  // helper returns a stepId from props by index
  getStepId(i: number): string {
    return this.props.steps[i].stepId;
  }
  // helper returns the stepId for the current step
  getCurrentStepId(): string {
    return this.props.steps[this.state.currentStep].stepId;
  }
  // helper returns the element ref for a stepId
  // this assumes that an element has already been set.  you could include undefined in the return to be safe
  getStepRef(stepId: string): StepElement {
    return this.stepRefs[stepId];
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refreshAnimation(0);
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }
  updateWidth() {
    this.refreshAnimation(this.state.currentStep);
  }
  navigationStepChange(key: number) {
    if (this.props.steps) {
      var validationState = true;
      if (key > this.state.currentStep) {
        for (var i = this.state.currentStep; i < key; i++) {
          const stepId = this.getStepId(i);
          const ref = this.stepRefs[stepId];
          if (ref.sendState !== undefined) {
            this.setState({
              allStates: {
                ...this.state.allStates,
                [stepId]: ref.sendState()
              }
            });
          }
          if (
            ref.isValidated !== undefined &&
            ref.isValidated() === false
          ) {
            validationState = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (validationState) {
        this.setState({
          currentStep: key,
          nextButton: this.props.steps.length > key + 1 ? true : false,
          previousButton: key > 0 ? true : false,
          finishButton: this.props.steps.length === key + 1 ? true : false
        });
        this.refreshAnimation(key);
      }
    }
  }
  nextButtonClick() {
    const currentId = this.getCurrentStepId();
    const currentRef = this.stepRefs[currentId];
    if (
      (this.props.validate
        && (
          (
            currentRef.isValidated !== undefined &&
            currentRef.isValidated()
          ) ||
          currentRef.isValidated === undefined
        )) ||
      this.props.validate === undefined
    ) {
      if (
        currentRef.sendState !== undefined
      ) {
        this.setState({
          allStates: {
            ...this.state.allStates,
            [currentId]: currentRef.sendState()
          }
        });
      }
      var key = this.state.currentStep + 1;
      this.setState({
        currentStep: key,
        nextButton: this.props.steps.length > key + 1 ? true : false,
        previousButton: key > 0 ? true : false,
        finishButton: this.props.steps.length === key + 1 ? true : false
      });
      this.refreshAnimation(key);
    }
  }
  previousButtonClick() {
    const currentId = this.getCurrentStepId();
    const currentRef = this.stepRefs[currentId];
    if (
      currentRef.sendState !== undefined
    ) {
      this.setState({
        allStates: {
          ...this.state.allStates,
          [currentId]: currentRef.sendState()
        }
      });
    }
    var key = this.state.currentStep - 1;
    if (key >= 0) {
      this.setState({
        currentStep: key,
        nextButton: this.props.steps.length > key + 1 ? true : false,
        previousButton: key > 0 ? true : false,
        finishButton: this.props.steps.length === key + 1 ? true : false
      });
      this.refreshAnimation(key);
    }
  }
  finishButtonClick() {
    const currentId = this.getCurrentStepId();
    const currentRef = this.stepRefs[currentId];
    if (
      (this.props.validate === false &&
        this.props.finishButtonClick !== undefined) ||
      (this.props.validate &&
        ((currentRef.isValidated !== undefined &&
          currentRef.isValidated()) ||
          currentRef.isValidated === undefined
          ) &&
        this.props.finishButtonClick !== undefined)
    ) {
      this.setState(
        {
          allStates: {
            ...this.state.allStates,
            [currentId]: currentRef.sendState?.()
          }
        },
        () => {
          this.props.finishButtonClick?.(this.state.allStates);
        }
      );
    }
  }
  refreshAnimation(index: number) {
    var total = this.props.steps.length;
    var li_width = 100 / total;
    var total_steps = this.props.steps.length;
    var move_distance =
      this.wizard.current?.children[0].offsetWidth / total_steps;
    var index_temp = index;
    var vertical_level = 0;

    var mobile_device = window.innerWidth < 600 && total > 3;

    if (mobile_device) {
      move_distance = this.wizard.current?.children[0].offsetWidth / 2;
      index_temp = index % 2;
      li_width = 50;
    }

    this.setState({ width: li_width + "%" });

    var step_width = move_distance;
    move_distance = move_distance * index_temp;

    var current = index + 1;

    if (current === 1 || (mobile_device === true && index % 2 === 0)) {
      move_distance -= 8;
    } else if (
      current === total_steps ||
      (mobile_device === true && index % 2 === 1)
    ) {
      move_distance += 8;
    }

    if (mobile_device) {
      vertical_level = parseInt((index / 2).toString(), 10);
      vertical_level = vertical_level * 38;
    }
    var movingTabStyle = {
      width: step_width,
      transform:
        "translate3d(" + move_distance + "px, " + vertical_level + "px, 0)",
      transition: "all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.29, 1.42, 0.79, 1)"
    };
    this.setState({ movingTabStyle: movingTabStyle });
  }
  render() {
    const { classes, title, subtitle, color, steps } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.wizardContainer} ref={this.wizard}>
        <Card className={classes.card}>
          <div className={classes.wizardHeader}>
            <h3 className={classes.title}>{title}</h3>
            <h5 className={classes.subtitle}>{subtitle}</h5>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.wizardNavigation}>
            <ul className={classes.nav}>
              {steps.map((prop: any, key: any) => {
                return (
                  <li
                    className={classes.steps}
                    key={key}
                    style={{ width: this.state.width }}
                  >
                    <a
                      href="#pablo"
                      className={classes.stepsAnchor}
                      onClick={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        this.navigationStepChange(key);
                      }}
                    >
                      {prop.stepName}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
            <div
              className={classes.movingTab + " " + classes[color]}
              style={this.state.movingTabStyle}
            >
              {steps[this.state.currentStep].stepName}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.content}>
            {steps.map((prop, key) => {
              const stepContentClasses = cx({
                [classes.stepContentActive]: this.state.currentStep === key,
                [classes.stepContent]: this.state.currentStep !== key
              });
              return (
                <div className={stepContentClasses} key={key}>
                  <prop.stepComponent
                    innerRef={(node) => this.stepRefs[prop.stepId] = node}
                    allStates={this.state.allStates}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div className={classes.footer}>
            <div className={classes.left}>
              {this.state.previousButton ? (
                <Button
                  className={this.props.previousButtonClasses}
                  onClick={() => this.previousButtonClick()}
                >
                  {this.props.previousButtonText}
                </Button>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            <div className={classes.right}>
              {this.state.nextButton ? (
                <Button
                  color="rose"
                  className={this.props.nextButtonClasses}
                  onClick={() => this.nextButtonClick()}
                >
                  {this.props.nextButtonText}
                </Button>
              ) : null}
              {this.state.finishButton ? (
                <Button
                  color="rose"
                  className={this.props.finishButtonClasses}
                  onClick={() => this.finishButtonClick()}
                >
                  {this.props.finishButtonText}
                </Button>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            <div className={classes.clearfix} />
          </div>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Wizard.defaultProps = {
  color: "rose",
  title: "Here should go your title",
  subtitle: "And this would be your subtitle",
  previousButtonText: "Previous",
  previousButtonClasses: "",
  nextButtonClasses: "",
  nextButtonText: "Next",
  finishButtonClasses: "",
  finishButtonText: "Finish",
  // I added these two for completeness
  finishButtonClick: () => {},
  validate: false,
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/8w8j9m)

Comment: @Linda-Paste actually your code works.
The only problem is this line --> export default withStyles(wizardStyle)(Wizard);
That gives me 
Argument of type 'typeof Wizard' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<ConsistentWith<{}, { classes: Record<"primary" | "warning" | "danger" | "success" | "info" | "rose" | "title" | "subtitle" | "steps" | "wizardContainer" | "card" | "content" | "left" | "right" | ... 8 more ... | "clearfix", string>; }>>'.
  Type 'typeof Wizard' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<ConsistentWith<{}, { classes: Record<"primary" | "warning" | "danger"